# Pass parameter to the backing bean of the new page while navigation

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I use a commandLink to navigate to another page:

```
<t:commandLink action="go_orderForm" immediate="true">
     <h:outputText value="#{order.number}" />
    <t:updateActionListener property="#{orderForm.orderId}"
                    value="#{order.id}" />
</t:commandLink>
```

This is working and setting the value of `order.id` to the backing bean `orderForm.orderId`.

In another place, I use a commandButton to call an action in the backing bean of the current page and navigate after to the new page:

```
<h:commandButton value="Create Batch" action="#{orderList.createBatchOrder}" />
```

The action in the backing bean looks like:

```
public String createBatchOrder() {
    // do something

    return "go_orderForm";
}
```

The `faces-config.xml` contains

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>go_orderForm</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/orderForm.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

How can I pass the parameter for `orderForm.orderId` when I navigate using the action in the backing bean?

Comment: You mean something like a flash scope to share variables?

Comment: Answer depends on whether you're using JSF 1.x or 2.x. The usage of Tomahawk component library and XML navigation rules suggest that you're actually still using the jurassic JSF 1.x. The answer from L.dev below however only works for JSF 2.x. JSF 2.x was introduced more than a decade ago already. Can't you upgrade to JSF 2.x? Nonetheless, the correct answer depends on whether you want the target page to be idempotent or not. The answer from L.dev below assumes it isn't idempotent (i.e. when you simply refresh the page, you might lose this information again, not sure if this is what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before redirect put your parameter to flash:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put(key, value);
```

After redirect you may get it by:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get(key);
```